# Xamarin.Forms: Communication between partial view's VM and Parent's VM

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a partial-view with its own ViewModel so I can use it in different `ContentPage` (s). However, this partial view must also have some properties that will be bound to the parent's VM. (and this should be without intervention of any third party libs such as Prism)

here is a sample:

## PrtialView

#### PrtialView.xaml:

```
<StackLayout  x:Class="....OtpVerificator" ...>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp1Entry"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp2Entry"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp3Entry"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp4Entry"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp5Entry"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="Otp6Entry"></Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

#### PrtialView.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class OtpVerificator : StackLayout
        {
           //.....
           // For example I want also set this property from the parent's view or vVM
            public static readonly BindableProperty TokenProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Token), typeof(string), typeof(OtpVerificator), default(string), Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.TwoWay);
            public string Token
            {
                get
                {
                    return (string)GetValue(TokenProperty);
                }
    
                set
                {
                    SetValue(TokenProperty, value);
                }
            }

 protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == TokenProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (Token != EntriesFullText)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Token.Length; i++)
                        otpEntries[i].Text = Token.Substring(i, 1);
                }
            }

           //......
        }


           
           // .......

 private string EntriesFullText
        {
            get => string.Join(string.Empty, otpEntries
                .Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
                .Select(e => e.Text[0]));
        }

private void OtpEntry_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Token != EntriesFullText)
                Token = EntriesFullText;

            var oldVal = e.OldTextValue ?? string.Empty;
            var newVal = e.NewTextValue ?? string.Empty;

            var entry = sender as BorderlessEntry; // .. and check for null

            var index = otpEntries.IndexOf(entry); // what if IndexOf returns -1?

            //  allow for a single val
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldVal))
                entry.Text = newVal.All(nw => nw.ToString() == oldVal) ? oldVal : entry.Text.Replace(oldVal, string.Empty);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
                return;

            var nextIndex = index + 1;

            if (nextIndex >= otpEntries.Length)
                entry.Unfocus();
            else
            {
                var next = otpEntries.ElementAt(nextIndex);
                next?.Focus();
            }
        }
    
    
        }
```

#### ParentView.xaml:


I know that `Token` belongs to the embedded VM, Hence I wrote Token2 to explain that it is different property of the PV that should be able to set from the Parent's view or from parent's VM (binding)

```
<ContentPage x:Class="....ParentPage">
   <partials:OtpVerificator x:Name="otpVerifier"
                                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                 ActionType="LoginConfirmation"
                                                 Token2="123658">
                        </partials:OtpVerificator>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give your parentView a name and bind like this :

```
Token2="{Binding BindingContext.token2 , Source={x:Reference parentView}}"
```

Here is the example:

```
<ContentPage x:Class="....ParentPage" x:Name="parentView">
    <partials:OtpVerificator x:Name="otpVerifier"
                                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                 ActionType="LoginConfirmation"
                                                 Token2="{Binding BindingContext.token2 , Source={x:Reference parentView}}">
    </partials:OtpVerificator>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: +1, Thank you for your pass, Please is there any way more implicit than this? I want the partial view shown like Native Views, in a way showing no trace for the embedded VM?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a way showing no trace for the embedded VM"?

Comment: I mean like normal binding way: Token2="{Binding token}"
also setting the BindingContext should not affect the embedded VM
 <partials:OtpVerificator.BindingContext>
//here the explicit vm (i.e. different than the embedded and affects only the token2 prop
 </partials:OtpVerificator.BindingContext>

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Normal binding won't affect the embedded VM.

Comment: I want it to be shown something like this
<partials:OtpVerificator x:Name="otpVerifier"
                                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                 ActionType="LoginConfirmation"
                                                 Token2="{Binding token2}">
    </partials:OtpVerificator>

Comment: please note that the embedded vm is bound to the OtpVerificator itself in the code behind

Comment: No, I don't think there is a more implicit way. The binding context you refer is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220631/discussion-between-abudawood-and-jack-hua-msft).